# How can boost signal disconnect signal?

Tags: boost, signals, disconnect

As [boost_offical_web_site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/function/faq.html) says, boost::function is not comparable。but I am doubt about the usage:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class B {
public:
    ~B() {
        printf("B dealloc:%p\n", this);
    }
    void OnSignalActive(void) {
        printf("B get signal address:%p\n", this);
    }
};

void test05() {
    boost::signals2::signal<void (void)> signalConnection;
    B b;
    
    auto v = boost::bind(&B::OnSignalActive, &b);
    auto u = boost::bind(&B::OnSignalActive, &b);
    
//    if (v == u) {//compile error
//
//    }
    
    boost::signals2::slot<void (void)> slot1(v);
    boost::signals2::slot<void (void)> slot2(v);
    
//    if (slot1.slot_function() == slot2) {//compile error
//
//    }
    
    boost::signals2::connection conn = signalConnection.connect(v);
    
    signalConnection();
    
    signalConnection.disconnect(u);
    
    signalConnection();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    test05();
    return 0;
}
```

the code *signalConnection.disconnect(u)* can disconnect signal and runs well.I suspend boost do comparision by slot. so I debug into source:

```
void do_disconnect(const T &slot, mpl::bool_<false> /* is_group */)
{
  shared_ptr<invocation_state> local_state =
    get_readable_state();
  typename connection_list_type::iterator it;
  for(it = local_state->connection_bodies().begin();
    it != local_state->connection_bodies().end(); ++it)
  {
    garbage_collecting_lock<connection_body_base> lock(**it);
    if((*it)->nolock_nograb_connected() == false) continue;
    if((*it)->slot().slot_function() == slot)
    {
      (*it)->nolock_disconnect(lock);
    }else
    {
      // check for wrapped extended slot
      bound_extended_slot_function_type *fp;
      fp = (*it)->slot().slot_function().template target<bound_extended_slot_function_type>();
      if(fp && *fp == slot)
      {
        (*it)->nolock_disconnect(lock);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

found that inner uses == to disconnect.one is slot_function(actual boost::function) and another is slot.
But when I manually create boost::signals2::slot. could not compare!

```
/main.cpp:303:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::operator==<boost::signals2::slot<void ()>>' requested here
if (slot1.slot_function() == slot2) {//compile error
```

I confused very much.

how can boost disconnect like this?
using slot & slot_function?
why manually create could not compare?

can someone help me!3Q in advance.

help me & answer the question.

Comment: After long time debug.It seems that actual comparsion is between boost::function & boost::bind. boost::function provides operator== as below:

template<class S, class R, class F, class L> bool operator==( function<S> const& f, _bi::bind_t<R, F, L> const& b )
{
    return f.contains( b );
}

Answer (score 0):

The actual line is

```
if((*it)->slot().slot_function().contains(slot))
```

Which indeed ends up comparing the functions type-erased targets, if the typeid matches. This behaviour may be overrided for your own types by creating your own overload of [`function_equal`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost/function_equal.html) to be found by ADL. (See also [Comparing Boost.Function Objects](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id-1.3.15.5.8))

Boost bind expressions can be compared if the bound expressions can be. Replacing with `std::bind` makes it fail.

> It's an implementation but indeed putting a stub like
>
> ```
> friend bool function_equal_impl(auto&&...) { return false; }
> ```
>
> Makes it compile with std::bind. Of course, it won't really compare now.

In short, don't use `disconnect(handler)` unless your handlers are comparable. If you have handlers that cannot be compared, use `scoped_connection` instead:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/143ce5c5db2afa6a)**

```cpp
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
namespace signals2 = boost::signals2;

#define TRACE(code) do { printf("%d: %s\n", __LINE__, #code); code; } while (0)

void test05() {
    signals2::signal<void()> signal;

    signals2::scoped_connection v = signal.connect([] { printf("Handler: V\n"); });
    signals2::scoped_connection u = signal.connect([] { printf("Handler: U\n"); });
    TRACE(signal());
    TRACE(v.disconnect());
    TRACE(signal());
}
```

Printing **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/143ce5c5db2afa6a)**

```
11: signal()
Handler: V
Handler: U
12: v.disconnect()
13: signal()
Handler: U
```

Comment: 3Q for your generous answer!
Did you mean boost::bind can be compared because of that it overrides "function_equal" ?
Still one left unclear:After digged in "contains" I found that 
template<class R, class F, class L> bool function_equal( bind_t<R, F, L> const & a, bind_t<R, F, L> const & b )
{
    return a.compare(b);
}
````
````
bool compare( this_type const & rhs ) const
{
    return ref_compare( f_, rhs.f_, 0 ) && l_ == rhs.l_;
}
````
It seems no typeid usage.if I set no-rtti property,the program does not affected.

Comment: B b;
    auto v = boost::bind(&B::OnSignalActive, &b);
    auto u = boost::bind(&B::OnSignalActive, &b);
    
    boost::_bi::bind_t v1 = v;
    boost::_bi::bind_t u1 = u;
    
    bool value = boost::_bi::function_equal(v1, u1);
    if (value) {
        printf("Done\n");
    }

runs well.

Comment: 1. boost::function can be compared according to the linked documentation. `boost::bind` can merely be compared like their component parts. Note that this will likely not do what you expect: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d49c8f18f3eae8e8 Because you seem to care about object identity, and Signals2 [internally copies the object](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0201e1251e2ed7f0) you need the (scoped) connection: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd5988747887c895 Note the static assert demonstrating that it doesn't even require the handlers to be comparable at all.

Comment: 2. regarding rtti it's probably a virtual inside the type-erasure container - you erase the type at assignment, but *it* knows. This is the same mechanism by which the default constructor of std::shared_ptr can store the concrete deleter type matching the actual type, even if the type lacks a virtual destructor

Comment: I got what you said.
1.boost::function's comparsion depends on  specialization of "function_equal".
2.boost::Signal2 uses contains(func) to compare the type-erased object in the boost::function. Of course，the type-erased object in the wrapper must be comparable(for class or struct can defines operator==).